# Owl Carousel arrows disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel-2

Owl Carousel arrows disappear when items = 4.

Images:
3 items, arrows working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCB2W.jpg 
4 items, arrows not working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opl9e.jpg

**HTML**

```
    <section id="sponsor">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="sponsor-carousel">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                        <img src="{{ asset('image/img-sponsor-ashurindo.png') }}" alt="" width="100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                        <img src="{{ asset('image/img-sponsor-air-asia.png') }}" alt="" width="100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                        <img src="{{ asset('image/img-sponsor-star-midas.png') }}" alt="" width="100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                        <img src="{{ asset('image/img-sponsor-fly-emirates.png') }}" alt="" width="100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#sponsor-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        responsiveClass:true,
        navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            768: {
                items: 4
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: at `768:` remove `Comma Sign` and try..

Comment: still not appear

Comment: now show your full working code here...

Comment: wait a minute, i edit my post

Comment: appear error when i edit html & js, "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Answer (score 0):

I tried same code with 5 items it is working fine, Please check your jquery version or HTML :

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="sponsor-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>5</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>6</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>7</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>8</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>9</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>10</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>11</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>12</h4>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sponsor-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        nav: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 3000,
        responsiveClass:true,
        margin: 10,
        navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        responsive: {
            0: {
              items: 1
            },
            768: {
              items: 5
            },
         }
    });
})
```

Comment: what version jquery do you use? i used 2.2.4

Comment: is it successful if using image in item?

Comment: Version: jQuery v3.3.1

Comment: I just checked, it turns out that owl-nav have class disabled why?, 
even though I have given the nav true value in js

Comment: make nav: true in js and try navText:['<button type="button" class="btn slider-left-btn"> </button>','<button type="button" class="btn slider-right-btn"> </button>'],

Comment: i have make nav:true, but when i inspect html in owl-nav there are disabled class